query always wrong in dart
I created a quiz and I have a problem. No matter whether the answer is right or wrong, it always says 'wrong'.
if (userAnswer != null && entry.value.containsKey(userAnswer) && entry.value[userAnswer]!) {
  print('Richtig!\n');
  score++;
} else {
  print('Falsch!\n');
}


You could add print(userAnswer); and print(entry.value);  and post the output with your question.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
